# How can I use Swift to detect if a playlist is currently playing?

Tags: ios, swift2

I am writing a music app (still using Swift 2.3), but can not figure out how to detect whether or not a playlist is currently playing.  I would like one of my Views to be able to display the title of a previously selected playlist (the one that would be currently playing).  Songs, Albums, Artists all have persistentIDs.  The trick here is that a song can exist on more than one playlist.  I found the following code stackoverflow.  Elsewhere in my code, I query the playlists, present them in a table, a playlist is choosen (by clicking a row), I query the list of songs, I start a song, and then following code will print the Title, Artist and Album correctly, but Playlist is nil.

```
let nowPlaying = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().nowPlayingItem
let Title = nowPlaying![MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
let Artist = nowPlaying![MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
let Album = nowPlaying![MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
let Playlist = nowPlaying![MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID] as? String
print("Title = ", Title)
print("Artist = ", Artist)
print("Album = ", Album)
print("Playlist = ", Playlist)
```

Elsewhere I have code that queries artists, albums and playlists.  I'd be grateful to anyone who could point me in the right direction.  Thanks